# Qt creator: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'

Tags: qt, boost

Trying to run the following code in Qt Creator on Win7 64bit.

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    ptime t = microsec_clock::universal_time();
    std::cout << to_iso_extended_string(t) << "Z\n";
}
```

This is my *.pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47"
CONFIG += boost
LIBS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\lib"
LIBS += -lboost_date_time-vc71-mt-1_47
```

I get the following error:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\boost\date_time\date_formatting.hpp:49: error: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_long_string() const'
>
> c:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\boost\date_time\date_formatting.hpp:44: error: undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::as_short_string() const'

How can I get this to work? I read that I need to build the date time lib but I'm not to sure how I would do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These boost library binaries are compiled with and for the Visual C++ compiler (you can guess by the 'vc71' in the file name), but you are using QtCreator with the MinGW compiler and you can't mix C++ libraries compiled with different compilers (only the C part of the library would be usable).

You can either continue to use MinGW and recompile boost yourself *, or change the compiler used by QtCreator in the project configuration, assuming you have installed any version of Visual C++ and the Qt binaries for that compiler.

<sub>* : Since MinGW can be configured with lot of different incompatible options, it is safer to recompile boost than using precompiled binaries, unless you are sure they were built with the same MinGW that is included in your Qt SDK.</sub>

Comment: But when I use visual studio I get the follow error: Error 6 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib' I installed boost using the c++ installer. I can find other libboost_date_time.lib files in /lib but they are not this one

Comment: If you downloaded VC++ boost binaries from boostpro.com, IIRC you have to choose the version(s) of VC++ binaries you want to install (and from their download page, the 10.0 seems to be among them)

Comment: And how do I do so that vs finds it? Its in C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\lib

Comment: Linker/input/Additinal dep: $(QTDIR)\lib\qtmaind.lib;$(QTDIR)\lib\QtDeclaratived4.lib;$(QTDIR)\lib\QtGuid4.lib;$(QTDIR)\lib\QtNetworkd4.lib;$(QTDIR)\lib\QtCored4.lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\lib\boost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies) gives "Error 6 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'"

Comment: fiex it. added it to linker/general/"addition lib dir"

Comment: You can keep using QtCreator as the IDE and use the VC++ compiler with the same .pro file (with the "vc100" .lib) , use "Ctrl+T" to change the current configuration, and if VC++ 2010 is not one of them, you can go to the "Projects" page and add it with the "Add" button at the top of the "Build Settings" page. You may also have other parameters to configure like the toolchain.

Comment: tried that. not too sure how to change it thought. have the build settings here and cant figure out where to change it. y QMAKESPEC is currently "win32-msvc2010", is that not right?